# How to insert a new row into a tableview from a different class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to access the tableView property (defined in the UITableViewController class) from a different class. Once I have accessed it I need to send it the method

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic:
```

This is my code, but it doesn't seem to insert the new row?

> [((MainViewController *)self.presentingViewController).tableView
>   insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path]
>   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your datasource modifies itself as well. So if you insert a new row, you need

–tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

to return 1 more than before, and

–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

to return the new cell. The TableView does not take care of those parts for you.

Here is a rough outline of what your code should look like.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
// Some code to add row to your datasource
[datasource addrow]
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```